# mysql query is bad i need help to show my products from my database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
    $consulta1="SELECT * FROM PRODUCTO LIMIT $empezarDesde,$contenidoPorPagina 
WHERE FAMILIA BETWEEN 0 AND 5 ORDER BY FAMILIA ASC";
      $resultado1 = $mysqli->query($consulta1);

      while($dato = $resultado1->fetch_assoc()){
...
}
```

I am doing a shopWeb and my query don´t work.

Comment: Your `LIMIT` clause is in the wrong place. For future reference: your question doesn’t include any explanation of what is wrong, what error messages you get, or other information to help anyone solve your problem. “My query don’t work” is not a clear problem statement.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn’t this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LIMIT should be at the end of the query...

```
$consulta1="SELECT * FROM PRODUCTO  
             WHERE FAMILIA BETWEEN 0 AND 5 
             ORDER BY FAMILIA ASC
             LIMIT $empezarDesde,$contenidoPorPagina";
```